# Why does closing a channel in defer statement panic?

Tags: go, goroutine

In the following example, a go routine is pumping values into unbuffered channel and the main function is iterating over it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

var chanStr chan string

func main() {
    go pump()
    fmt.Println("iterating ...")
    for val := range chanStr {
        fmt.Printf("fetched val: %s from channel\n", val)
    }
}

func pump() {
    defer close(chanStr)
    chanStr = make(chan string)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("pumping seq %d into channel\n", i)
        chanStr <- "val" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    }
    //close(chanStr)
}
```

The function panics with the following output:

```
iterating ...                                             
pumping seq 1 into channel                                
pumping seq 2 into channel                                
fetched val: val1 from channel                            

......

fetched val: val4 from channel                            
pumping seq 5 into channel                                
panic: close of nil channel                               

goroutine 5 [running]:                                    
main.pump()                                               
        C:/personal/gospace/go-rules/test.go:26 +0x1a6    
created by main.main                                      
        C:/personal/gospace/go-rules/test.go:11 +0x4e
```

However if I comment the defer statement and close right after the for loop in the goroutine `pump` , the receiver doesn't panic. 
*What's the difference in both the cases?* Looks like defer closes the channel before the value is received but the regular close waits.

Also when I built using the race detector on, even in the regular close it flags a potential race condition (I'm not able recreate the race every time). Does it imply that both of those ways are not right in gracefully closing the channel?

**UPDATE:**
For all those commenting, I know what's the issue. I have to create the channel at the first line in the `main()` function. However I'm running on windows with go1.12 and I observed this behavior.
Obviously I didn't fake the output. I'm consistently recreating the panic using defer statement and not even once a panic occurred when I closed the channel immediately after the for loop in `pump()`

Comment: The race is where the main go-routine will read from a chan value that will be altered by the background go-routine. Create the channel ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very racy, in different ways:

1. You have the potential (in fact, it's very likely) that you'll start reading from the channel in your `for val` loop, before the goroutine actually initializes the channel, leading to a deadlock.

   ```
   iterating ...
   pumping seq 1 into channel
   fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
   ```

   In fact, this is the only behavior I observe executing your code, as-is, both locally, or in the playground.
2. If I add a delay,

   ```
    fmt.Println("iterating ...")
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond) // Delay ensures the channel has been created
    for val := range chanStr {
   ```

   I then do observe your noted behavior:

   ```
   iterating ...
   pumping seq 1 into channel
   fetched val: val1 from channel
   pumping seq 2 into channel
   pumping seq 3 into channel
   fetched val: val2 from channel
   fetched val: val3 from channel
   pumping seq 4 into channel
   pumping seq 5 into channel
   fetched val: val4 from channel
   fetched val: val5 from channel
   panic: close of nil channel
   ```

   The reason for this is that you're calling `close(chanStr)` while `chanStr` is still nil. If you call your `defer` after you create the channel:

   ```
   func pump() {
       chanStr = make(chan string)
       defer close(chanStr)
   ```

   you'll solve that problem.

To solve both races, you need to initialize the channel *before* calling the goroutine. Complete code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

var chanStr chan string

func main() {
    chanStr = make(chan string)
    go pump(chanStr)
    fmt.Println("iterating ...")
    for val := range chanStr {
        fmt.Printf("fetched val: %s from channel\n", val)
    }
}

func pump(chanStr chan string) {
    defer close(chanStr)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("pumping seq %d into channel\n", i)
        chanStr <- "val" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    }
}
```

To further illustrate that the problem is that `defer close(chanStr)` evaluates `chanStr` immediately (while it's still `nil`), consider this (not recommended!) alternative solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var chanStr chan string

func main() {
    go pump()
    fmt.Println("iterating ...")
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    for val := range chanStr {
        fmt.Printf("fetched val: %s from channel\n", val)
    }
}

func pump() {
    defer func() {
        close(chanStr)
    }()
    chanStr = make(chan string)
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("pumping seq %d into channel\n", i)
        chanStr <- "val" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    }
}
```

In this case, the deferred function is a closure over `chanStr`, so `chanStr`'s evaluation is delayed until the actual execution. In this version, when the deferred function executes, `chanStr` is no longer nil, so no panic.

Comment: Since channel is just a reference and the `pump()` holds a closure to that reference, by the time `defer close(chanStr)` gets called it shouldn't be `nil` channel anymore right?

Comment: A channel isn't a reference, though. And whether `pump()` is a closure or not doesn't matter. `close(chanStr)` is evaluated immediately, even though the `close` function itself isn't executed until the function exits.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another example to illustrate that the problem is the early evaluation of `chanStr`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility where the main go-routine may read from the channel before it's created. That is your data race.

The channel should be created *before* starting your go-routine.

Fix: https://play.golang.org/p/O7pgM05KEtI

Comment: That is _a_ race, but not the one the OP asked about. :) This particular race leads to a deadlock, not closing a nil channel.

Comment: @Flimzy true. But my fix of creating the channel before the go routine solves both race conditions. It not worth contorting the code to work for a channel value that may change. Instead, fix the code so the channel value never changes.

Comment: Yes, it's the same solution I offered in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted had a deadlock scenario. As Flimzy pointed out, you probably didn't post the same codes.

Here's the updated code that should work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    chanStr := make(chan string)

    go pump(chanStr)
    fmt.Println("iterating ...")
    for val := range chanStr {
        fmt.Printf("fetched val: %s from channel\n", val)
    }
}

func pump(ch chan string) {
    defer close(ch)

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("pumping seq %d into channel\n", i)
        ch <- "val" + strconv.Itoa(i)
    }
    //close(chanStr)
}
```

The issue in this case was that you created the channel inside the `pump` function so the main function didn't know how to consume the data and was causing a deadlock because there was no consumer.

Comment: "It's happening because the channel is closing before the main function can consume the data" -- No, this is not accurate. It's happening because the `defer close(chanStr)` is being called before `chanStr` is defined. You'll notice that in the failed run, data _is consumed_ from the channel, prior to the panic.

Comment: That part is not related to the code he posted, it was answer to why reading from the closed channel was causing panic. This part was added before I ran his code and noticed the deadlock.

Comment: Reading from the channel isn't causing a panic, though. Closing the channel is causing the panic. The OP's own output shows successful reads from the channel.

Comment: I think something like that was mentioned in the post but you're right. I stand corrected.

Comment: Your solution _will_ fix the problem, by the way... just not for the reasons you've explained :)

Comment: What's wrong with the rest of the part? Just curious :)